# LVM error causing fall back to initramfs on boot after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: lvm, boot, initramfs

I've recently updated Ubuntu from an older LTS release (12.04) to 14.04 LTS and upon reboot, ubuntu fails to load and an error in `/sbin/lvm` is shown:

```
There appears to be one or more degraded LVM volumes, and your root device may 
depend on the LVM volumes being online. 
One or more of the following LVM volumes are degraded:
/sbin/lvm: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.5: undefined symbol: PC
Gave up waiting for root device...
ALERT! /dev/mapper/my-server-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

It seems like the **/sbin/lvm: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.5: undefined symbol: PC** is the culprit, and I suppose that `/sbin/lvm` wasn't correctly linked with the appropriate libraries, causing the boot image to be unable to run LVM at all, so the LVM volumes does not load.

**What I have tried**

1. Running `lvm` in the initramfs shell returns the same error about symbol lookup.
2. Removing `/usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.5` and running `lvm` will make it throw an error about `libreadline.so.5` not being available instead.
3. `vgchange` is not a valid command (I assume it requires `lvm` and it should be ran using `lvm vgchange -ay` instead?)

I *guess* that I should try to re-build the boot image to include a correct copy of `lvm`. However I am not sure how to do that (should I boot a 14.04 live disk, and install `lvm2`, or should I do some more steps? How can I modify initramfs and fix it?) and I am afraid I mess up the existing LVM configuration. How should I do that? Thanks!